# call non static method from static method in android

Tags: java, android, static

I tried to call non static method from static method but without any result ,my application works crash 
my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setAuth();
        ///

        ///



    }
    public static void setAuth() {

                new MainActivity().d();
        }
    public void d()
    {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fff",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    }
```

Is it permissible to  call non static method from static method in android??
and how???

Comment: post our crash error log !

Comment: First off all you can't do `new MainActivity()` for an Activity. I think your main task is to show Toast. So pass a Context object as param to setAuth() and show your toast using that context object.

Comment: You should consider spending a bit more time on simple Java programming before trying to make an Android app.

Comment: code isn't from my application, I tried simple code ,if the code  work then change  my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static method in a class must be able to be executed without any reference to an instantiation of the class:

```
class MyClass {
    int information;
    static int usefulNumber = 72;

    int method() {
        return information;
    }

    static int methodStatic() {
        // Cannot refer to information
        // But can refer to usefulNumber
    }
}
```

By definition therefore, it cannot execute a non-static method in the class because that method doesn't exist unless, as @RhinoFeeder says, you have instantiated the class *and* passed that instantiation to the static class:

```
    static int methodStatic2(MyClass myClass) {
        return myClass.method();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is if you have access to an instance of the class that contains the non-static method.

EDIT: I realized this answer sounds empty without a further explanation, since you do new-up a `MainActivity`.

`new MainActivity().d();`

Will not work in Android, as you cannot create a new Activity that way.

Comment: Honestly, I would abandon this design all together.  I would make setAuth take in a `Context`, and use that context to create the Toast in that method, axing `d()` all together.  If you are set on the design you have now, @NeilTownsend provided a solid answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void setAuth(MainActivity activity) {
       activity.d();
}
```

That simple.

`new MainActivity().d();` calls the method of another instance of the activity.

Comment: Ok, try to call d() method from onCreate method and remove the call of the static method. to check if that's what is really causing the crash. because I don't believe it is.