# How to call method in android so able to run code

Tags: java, android

I want to create a simple calculator in Android, in my way I get an error on **calling a fuction** that i have already **declared**. Any Android Expert here that can help me?

```
public class CalculatorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);
    }

    //Start my method

    public void calculator(View v) {
        Button btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0);
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        Button btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        Button btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);

        TextView textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if (btn0.isPressed() == true) {

            textViewResult.setText(textViewResult + "0");
        } else if (btn1.isPressed() == true) {
            textViewResult.setText(textViewResult + "1");

        }

    }
       //End my method

    //I want to call that fucntion, and i get an error
    calculator();


}
```

Comment: use    calculator(); inside onCreate.

Comment: call `calculator();` inside your `onCreate`

Comment: `calculator(View v)` needs view as parameter. You're missing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [call non static method from static method in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089568/call-non-static-method-from-static-method-in-android)

Comment: you can not call method in Class block only.

Comment: This is the first question by this user. He asked a simple question. I'm unsure why this question is being downvoted. Perhaps it resembles another question, but a new user may be unable to find them. StackOverflow should be a place where newcomers can ask questions and get answers. Perhaps constructive comments about how to improve questions in the future would serve a better purpose than downvoting this user's first question.

Answer (score 0):

You should call that method inside `OnCreate()`

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);
      calculator();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class CalculatorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);
        calculator();
    }

    //Start my method

    public void calculator() {
        Button btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0);
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        Button btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        Button btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);

        TextView textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if (btn0.isPressed() == true) {

            textViewResult.setText(textViewResult + "0");
        } else if (btn1.isPressed() == true) {
            textViewResult.setText(textViewResult + "1");

        }

    }
       //End my method
}
```

Comment: Error apperars that says "calculator
(View)
in CalculatorActivity cannot be applied
to
() "

Comment: change this line   **public void calculator()** change this

Comment: should add return type? as public int calculator()

Comment: what are you exactly doing brother?

Comment: broH, am just trying to call that method in many ways. whenever and where ever i want to call calculator() method is highlighted an error! :(

Comment: please copy and paste my answer. this function is calling.

Comment: When i run the App then i click the OnClick Button, the App will Terminate and then says: "Could not find method calculator (CalculatorActivity)(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view..."

Comment: you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code:

```
public class CalculatorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);
        //I want to call that fucntion, and i get an error
        calculator();
        }

        //Start my method

        public void calculator() {
            Button btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0);
            Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
            Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
            Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
            Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
            Button btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
            Button btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);

            TextView textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

            if (btn0.isPressed() == true) {

                textViewResult.setText(textViewResult + "0");
            } else if (btn1.isPressed() == true) {
                textViewResult.setText(textViewResult + "1");

            }

        }
           //End my method
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

call calculator() method inside your onCreate() method

Answer (score 0):

Call calculator(); inside your onCreate()

```
   public class CalculatorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);
        calculator();
    }

    //Start my method

    public void calculator(View v) {
        Button btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0);
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        Button btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        Button btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);

        TextView textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if (btn0.isPressed() == true) {

            textViewResult.setText(textViewResult + "0");
        } else if (btn1.isPressed() == true) {
            textViewResult.setText(textViewResult + "1");

        }

    }
}
```

Now it's going to working charm

Comment: @Abdirahman Looskey use this code. it's simple call a method.